# iOS xCode5 Unsupported compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42' error when compiler set to LLVM 5.0

Tags: ios6, ios7, xcode5, llvm-gcc, llvm5

I'm trying to open one of my older projects, that was built using iOS 6.0. The project used to compile fine, but when opened under xCode 5, I get this cryptic error message.

```
Unsupported compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42' selected for architecture 'armv7'
Unable to determine concrete GCC compiler for file /Users/alexanderstone/Desktop/Development/RestKit/Vendor/NXJSON/NSError+Extensions.m of type sourcecode.c.objc.
Unable to determine concrete GCC compiler for file /Users/alexanderstone/Desktop/Development/RestKit/Vendor/NXJSON/NXDebug.m of type sourcecode.c.objc.
Unable to determine concrete GCC compiler for file /Users/alexanderstone/Desktop/Development/RestKit/Vendor/NXJSON/NXJsonParser.m of type sourcecode.c.objc.
Unable to determine concrete GCC compiler for file /Users/alexanderstone/Desktop/Development/RestKit/Vendor/NXJSON/NXJsonSerializer.m of type sourcecode.c.objc.
```

I've checked both project build settings, and they appear correct - LLVM 5.0 is selected as compiler for both.

[image]

[image]

Additionally, I checked the .m files that compiler complains about, and do not see any reference to GCC there. There are some `ASSERT()` and other macros, but I don't know if they are compiler-specific.

How can I resolve the llvmgcc4.2 compiler missing in xCode 5, when all subprojects appear to be set to llvm5.0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Found this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530392/unsupported-compiler-gcc-4-2-selected-for-architecture-armv7/21786244#21786244). For me the solution was to go to Editor>Validate Project settings for both the child and the Restkit projects.

Answer (score 3):

One solution of this problem is that i have resolved when i was facing this issue is just go to Build Settings-> Build Options-> Compiler for c++ set to Default and your problem wil be solved. [see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxBP8.png)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, for opening in XCode 7 and for architecture 'i386', setting the compiler to 'Default compiler (Apple LLVM 7.1)' is one solution.